# Playing RTP stream from embedded device using sockets

Tags: c++, vlc, rtp

I'm writing an application on an embedded device which receives an RTP stream which carries G.729, PCM or H.264. The packets arrive to my application as a char* to the RTP packet. I would like to be able to see or listen to the stream (as a test), but on this device I don't have player. I thought I may forward this stream to a socket and play the RTP stream somewhere else, like on a Linux machine running a player. Would this be possible? I don't have RTSP, only RTP. Is VLC, for instance, a possible way to do this? Can I simply send the RTP packets to the socket to play them on the other side?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, you cannot. simple RTP doesn't contain any info about the stream format etc., only info about the packet itself: sequence number, timestamp, additional synchronization info. the simplest way to stream RTP is RTP/MPEG TS ([MPEG Transport Stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream)).

unfortunately I don't know ready to use solution. VLC can stream (and play) such streams over UDP from a file, so it takes required info from file container format. Such solution could take external stream description in [SDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Description_Protocol) format and your actual RTP packets

[EDIT] btw, it's weird that you receive just RTP stream w/o any description of its format, usually its description is provided somehow by RTSP, MPEG-TS or something else

Comment: It seems that writing this SDP is not simple. The RFC seems quite complex. Do you have any link I can refer to to write one for PCMU stream or H.264 stream? Thanks for your answer. I think this is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

example of SDP that contains H.264 stream:

```
Server: rtsp server

Content-type: application/sdp

Content-base: rtsp://[some URL]

Content-length: 505



v=0

o=rtsp 1295996924 1590699491 IN IP4 0.0.0.0

s=RTSP Session

i=rtsp server

c=IN IP4 192.168.1.2

t=0 0

a=control:*

m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 97

a=rtpmap: 97 mpeg4-generic/8000/1

a=fmtp: 97 streamtype=5; profile-level-id=15; objectType=2; mode=AAC-hbr;

a=range:npt=now-

a=control:trackID=0

m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96

a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000

a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=42E015; sprop-parameter-sets=Z0LgFdoHgtE=,aM4wpIA=; packetization-mode=1

a=range:npt=now-

a=framesize:96 480-352

a=control:trackID=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can forward RTP packets over a UDP socket.

Comment: Ok, so I forward opening a UDP socket and can I use VLC on the other side? File->Open netwrok...->Open RTP/UDP Stream and then as a protocol what do I select? I suppose RTP as it is the actual protocol. Am I right? Is this the correct way to go? Data inside the RTP header should be sufficient to VLC to understand what is inside the payload and to render the content, right? Thanks!

Comment: RTP is the protocol, and it specifies the actual media payload type in each RTP packet header.  Many RTP payload types are registered with IANA with static/default parameters (clock rate, etc).  However, it is possible for other parameters to be used.  SIP/SDP, RTSP, or any of several other protocols, are generally used to announce/negotiate RTP parameters before the actual RTP stream is transmitted.  I do not know if/how VLC handles that.